# StackStash - Stackoverflow offline reader for iOS

Tags: app, iphone, data-dump, ipad, offline

### iPhone Screenshot

[image: iPad Screenshot]

### iPad Screenshot

[image: iPad Screenshot]

## About

**[StackStash](http://stackstash.com)** lets you carry all of Stackoverflow data in your pocket.

We built this app because we find our productively as programmers plummets when we do not have connectivity and cannot search for stuff on stackoverflow. Now we never have to be away from stackoverflow again - and you don't have to be either.

On installation, the app will prompt you to download the data to your device. This is a compressed repository (3.6 GB in size). You can pause and resume the download. The data is downloaded only on a WiFi network.

**Please note**: The Stackoverflow data is from the Aug 2012 dump provided by StackExchange Inc under the Creative Commons CC BY-SA licence. (This is the latest available data as of Feb 2013.)

- More than 3.4 million questions and 6.8 million answers
- Powerful micro search engine optimized to search quickly through tags, questions, answers and comments in one simple responsive search box
- Instant search - search results update as you type your query
- Optimized layout for easy browsing on the iPhone or iPad
- History and Bookmarks
- Font size adjustment

AppStore Link: http://appstore.com/stackstashstackoverflowofflinereader 
Contact: support@bitmagic.in